# fetching mulitple branches from the Origin in a different directory structure

Tags: git, github

I have cloned the repo of my project which contains almost 10 different branches, 
i usually work on 2-3 branches simultaneously so do i need to clone the repo 3 times and then switch them to different branches .
or can i  create three different directory structures from the repo, so that i can import them as 3 different projects in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Git, by design, makes it trivially easy to convert from one branch to another including having work-in-progress saved (with 'git stash').  You might consider a more structured development process whereby you work on one branch at a time, complete a small bit of work, commit it and then move on - either to another branch or another 'unit of work' on the same branch.

If you must work on three branches at once then clone your project's repo three times and have three eclipse projects; keep all of them separate other than when you push and pull each clone back to the project repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have them as separate directories for Eclipse projects, you'd be best off just making 3 clones.

A single clone is usually best associated with a single working directory. (Things get complicated if that's not the case.)